# UIAlertAction not displaying passed message

Tags: ios, uialertview, nsnotificationcenter, swift2

I'm able to successfully pass a string a message between two classes but my `UIAlertAction` is not displaying the message.

**Code sending message**

```
var message = String()

Alamofire.request(.POST, endPoint, headers: Auth_header, parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON)
        .validate()
        .responseJSON {
        response in

        switch response.result {
        case .Success(let data):
            let value = JSON(data)
            if value["message"].string != nil {
                message = String(value["message"])
                let dic = ["message": message]
                print("hello")
                NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("notification",object: nil, userInfo: dic)
            }

            onCompletion()

        case .Failure(let error):
            print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
            onError?(error)
        }
```

**Code receiving and displaying message**

```
import UIKit

class TaskDetailsViewController: UIViewController {


@IBAction func submitBtn(sender: AnyObject) {
     loadTasks()
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(TaskDetailsViewController.displayMessage(_:)), name: "notification", object: nil)

}

func displayMessage(notification: NSNotification) {

    if let message = notification.userInfo!["message"]{

        //initialize Alert Controller
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Success", message: message.string, preferredStyle: .Alert)
        print(message)
        print("world")
        //Initialize Actions
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default){
            (action) -> Void in
            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        }

        //Add Actions
        alertController.addAction(okAction)

        //Present Alert Controller
        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
}
```

**My print out**

```
hello
  Score created.
world
```

[image: Output not shown]

Comment: what do you mean? Isn't the issue at the method displaying the alert since the message can be passed just fine

Answer (score 1):

I think your `message.string` is `nil` when passed to `UIAlertController`. Check it twice.

Print `message` after getting so you know that what you get in it.

You can put breakpoints also to check that you are getting data or not.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I just needed to change `message.string` to `message as? String` in my displayMessage function

Answer (score 0):

In success block:

```
case .Success(let data):
        let value = JSON(data)
        if let message = value["message"] as? String {  
            print("message")             
            let dic = ["message": message]
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("notification",object: nil, userInfo: dic)
        }
```

In alert controller presentation:

```
if let message = notification.userInfo!["message"] as? String {

    //initialize Alert Controller
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Success", message: message, preferredStyle: .Alert)
    print(message)
    print("world")
    //Initialize Actions
    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default){
        (action) -> Void in
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

    //Add Actions
    alertController.addAction(okAction)

    //Present Alert Controller
    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

If it's not coming the problem is the message string is nil or the message string is empty string("").

Answer (score 0):

`NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(TaskDetailsViewController.displayMessage(_:)), name: "notification", object: nil)` has to be in `func displayMessage(notification: NSNotification)` like:

```
func displayMessage(notification: NSNotification){
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(TaskDetailsViewController.displayMessage(_:)), name: "notification", object: nil)
// Your code
}
```

And then you remove the observer:

```
deinit{
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver
}
```